# Nginx doesn't serve asset files

Tags: nginx

This is my config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php;

    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|txt|srt|swf)$ {
        root /var/www/public;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }    

    location ~ /\.ht {
           deny all;
    }
}
```

My css files is placed in `/var/www/public/css/test.css`. When I go to `localhost:1234/css/test.css` i get nginx's 404 error. Normal pages like index page (`localhost:1234`) work. 
When I edit config:

```
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|txt|srt|swf)$ {
    return 200 debug;
    root /var/www/capitol/public;
}
```

I get `debug` message.

I've tried a lot of solutions from similar questions but none of them works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve problem by reinstalling nginx (not sure if it was necessary) and using this config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/public;
    index index.php;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```